# Can I use a z test to compare two samples if there is a significant difference in the size?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have to compare two unequal size samples from a population of 53k. One has a proportion of 56% and size of 50k and the other has a proportion of 50% and size of 3k. Can I do a two proportion z test to compare to make a case that the proportion of sample 1 is greater than sample 2?
Does the difference in the sample size pose an issue?

Some more info:
Here is the situation: Lets say I had 53k people and 50k received treatment A and 3k received treatment B. From the 3k, 50% showed positive results and from the 50k, 56% showed positive effect. How can I conclude that my treatment A was more effective than treatment B? I am looking for a way to make that case.

Comment: A z-test depends on sample size, not on population size.

Comment: Lets say I have a population of 53k which I have divided into 2 samples which are 50k and 3k. Can I use a z test then? Does the sample size difference pose a problem?

Comment: A difference in sample size doesn't pose a problem, but if your sample is the entire population, then you can't really use a z-test because your measurements of $\hat{p}$ are actually measurements of $p$. There's no uncertainty from sampling in your measurement since you have the entire population in your sample.

Comment: You perform this two sample $z$ test to see if there is a significant difference between two *population* proportions, not two sample proportions. If you have two different samples from the same population, then you really have two different estimates for the single (unknown) population proportion $ p$. A two sample $z$ test isn't appropiate.

Comment: Here is the situation: Lets say I had 53k people and 50k received treatment A  and 3k received treatment B. From the 3k, 50% showed positive results and from the 50k, 56% showed positive effect. How can I conclude that my treatment A was more effective than treatment B? I am looking for a way to make that case.

Comment: A "population" in this situation shouldn't be regarded as the collection of all $53,000$ people. You need to abstract your understanding of a statistical population. Think about Population $A$ as the collection of all people who will ever be treated using treatment $A$ and similarly for population $B$. Here's a less ambiguous example. Suppose you have two coins $C_1,C_2$ with probability of turning up heads on a single coin toss being $p_1,p_2$ respectively. You flip $C_1$ a total of $n_1=50,000$ times and observe $x_1=28,000$ heads.

Comment: Then you flip $C_2$ a total of $n_2=3,000$ times and observe $x_2=1,500$ heads. You wouldn't regard $n_1+n_2=53,000$ as a population size since you could theoretically repeat this experiment infinitely many times. If your null hypothesis is $H_0:p_1=p_2$ then the pooled proportion $\hat{p}=\frac{x_1+x_2}{n_1+n_2}$ is your best estimate for this common proportion. Now if $\hat{p}_1=\frac{x_1}{n_1}$ and $\hat{p}_2=\frac{x_2}{n_2}$ then $$z=\frac{\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2}{\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})\Big(\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}\Big)}}$$ is your appropiate test statistic.

Comment: In your situation $\hat{p}_A=0.56$ is your estimator for $p_{A}$, the probability that a randomly selected patient who receives treatment $A$ shows a positive effect. Similarly for $\hat{p}_B=0.5$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Do you think I can use the prop.test() function in r which gives the chi squared test? See this for more info: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2009/07/comparison-of-two-proportions-parametric-z-test-and-non-parametric-chi-squared-methods/

Comment: Btw Matthew and Amaan thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: @Seeker_123 The $\chi^2$ test is a non$-$parametric test and generally has lower power than your parametric two sample $z$ test. Since the consequences of a Type II error here are rather severe (claiming the treatments are equally effective when, in reality, treatment $A$ is better than treatment $B$) and there is no reason to avoid a parametric test (you have at least ten observed successes and failures in each sample) I would proceed with the two sample $z$ test if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In R, the procedure `prop.test` uses sizes of the two
samples (which may differ) and counts of 'successes' in
the two samples.

Then the test is as shown below:
The very small P-value indicates a highly significant
difference between the proportions $\hat p_1 =0.56$ and
$\hat p_2 =   0.50.$ [Because of the large sample sizes
I have not used the continuity correction `cor=F`.]

```
p1 = .56; n1 = 50000; x1 = round(p1*n1)
p2 = .50; n2 = 3000;  x2 = round(p2*n2)
prop.test(c(x1,x2), c(n1,n2), cor=F)


    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(x1, x2) out of c(n1, n2)
X-squared = 41.284, df = 1, p-value = 1.317e-10
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.04158663 0.07841337
sample estimates:
 prop 1 prop 2 
   0.56   0.50
```

*Notes:* (1) The `X-squared` statistic shown in the
output is the square of the normal $Z$-statistic.

(2) The version of the test used here is the one in the (yellow) note at the end of
[this page](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/9/9.4)
so that the confidence interval 'matches' the test. [If the 95% CI does not include $0,$ then the two proportions are significantly different
at the 5% level.]

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

The R method provided above is correct for this specific case.

The statistics is a Z statistics, but you have to be careful on how you calculate.

You can find a formula in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_statistic, and searching for 'Two-proportion z-test'. The page also provides when you can use Z statistics.

The above web page provides formulas for many statistical tests: so you can use for other analyses.

Comment: Thank you very much!!